# Addressbook address selecting using ios5 with ARC

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios5, automatic-ref-counting

Being fairly new to objective-c and developing for ios I'm trying to figure out how to implement the addressbook code from [`Address Book Programming Guide for iOS`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/ContactData/Conceptual/AddressBookProgrammingGuideforiPhone/Chapters/QuickStart.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007744-CH2-SW1).

I want to be able to log the address a user clicked on in the addressbook.

I managed to implement the addressbook in my app.

In ios4 the following 'works':

```
- (BOOL)peoplePickerNavigationController:(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker 
      shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson:(ABRecordRef)person  
                                property:(ABPropertyID)property 
                              identifier:(ABMultiValueIdentifier)identifier
{
    if (property == kABPersonAddressProperty)  // if tapped is equal to a phone property
    {
        NSLog(@"Address tapped!");
        NSMutableDictionary * cfaddress;
        ABMultiValueRef address = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonAddressProperty); 
        for(CFIndex i = 0; i < ABMultiValueGetCount(address); i++) {
            if(identifier == ABMultiValueGetIdentifierAtIndex (address, i)) { //if tapped number identifier is the same as identifier number tapped
                cfaddress = ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(address, i); // copy the number to CFSTRING number
            }
        }        

        NSLog(@"%@", [cfaddress objectForKey:@"City"]);    
        NSLog(@"%@", [cfaddress objectForKey:@"Street"]);

        // City and street present ?

        if([cfaddress objectForKey:@"City"] && [cfaddress objectForKey:@"Street"]){
            NSLog(@"STAD EN STRAAT");
        }
        else{
            NSLog(@"GEEN STAD EN/OF STRAAT");
        }
    }

    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    return YES;
}
```

Unfortunately in ios5 with Automatic reference counting on this gives me the following error:

> error: Automatic Reference Counting Issue: Implicit conversion of a non-Objective-C pointer type 'CFTypeRef' (aka 'const void *') to 'NSMutableDictionary *' is disallowed with ARC

I'm guessing my way of doing this (for ios4) wasn't a good way anyway and I would really appreciate some suggestions on how to achieve this. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Add a cast to `NSMutableDictionary *` or use one of the autorelease constructors to be more explicit.

Comment: Could you please explain the two options with examples ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

repalace this

```
cfaddress = ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(address, i);
```

with this

```
cfaddress = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:(NSDictionary *)ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(address, i)];
```

Comment: Thank you Eugene! It works, but I had to add this "(__bridge)"

The following seems to work:
cfaddress = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:(__bridge NSDictionary *)ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(address, i)];

Comment: @Laurens You need to annotate the cast because ARC forbids standard casts between pointers to Objective-C objects and pointers of other types, such as pointers to CoreFoundation objects. Also, since `ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex` returns a retained object (as per the Create Rule), you want to use `__bridge_transfer` instead of `__bridge` to let ARC know that this object is already retained, and it doesn't need to retain the object again (otherwise it will leak).